# How do things work when multiple game saves try to punt each other around?

Tags: spore

I have multiple saved games. One of them intends to eventually ally with the Grox. Another intends to wipe out all other empires. A third intends to control the galaxy via trade.

At some point, some of these games will run into each other and try to stomp each other out. I know that they can't destroy each other's homeworlds, but won't they still be able to take over the rest of their planets? Would I basically lose work in one file while I progress in another?

And how does this interact with creating a new game that happens to be inside an other-save antagonistic empire?

Answer (score 2):

> Won't they still be able to take over the rest of their planets?

Yes.

> Would I basically lose work in one file while I progress in another?

Only if, while playing the other file, something happens to undo progress in the other. If you don't directly attack your existing save file empires, and they never get into any trouble of their own accord, they'll be fine.

> And how does this interact with creating a new game that happens to be inside an other-save antagonistic empire?

On reaching Space, the new game will be in an area where many planets are already run by a large, antagonistic empire, similar to any NPC race, except that its homeworld is indestructible.

It's been a while since I played, but unless they've made some very sweeping changes (a quick skim of some other sites says they didn't), it's probably best to think of it like this: Spore only really has one save file. In that file, there's information about a huge amount of worlds, and more are generated on the fly as you explore. Some of those worlds have NPC races on them, some have races you control, and others are empty. But if you're not actively controlling a race, then that whole race behaves almost exactly the same as an NPC race, with the exception of their homeworld being immune to pretty much everything.

If you want to run multiple separate empires, without them getting in each others' way, you're probably best off trying to keep them each to their own arm of the Galaxy. If you plan on doing something incredibly wide-sweeping and drastic, like conquering literally every other empire, you may wish to install Spore on another computer if possible, or else do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this wiki article](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Saved_game), you cannot destroy, capture, or conquer a saved planet.  You can, however, ally with yourself.

```
When starting up a game, the player must select or create a race on any of the
planets shown in the arms of the galaxy. It is possible to fly to one of your
saved games using a different saved game. You cannot destroy this planet, but you
may become allies with them. The player cannot use any kind of dangerous weapons
on the saved planet. Saved games cannot be captured or conquered if the current
player ends up at war with that file. When the player deletes a saved game, that
planet will become computer controlled. Players' creatures only appear on saved
game planets when they have reached game stages later than the Creature Stage, so
that they do not take up a slot in the planet's food web.
```

Comment: I already read that article. It doesn't tell me things like what happens to the source file when non-homeworlds are taken over, or how the game handles making a new game on a system deep inside a different file's empire, which is why I stated those in the question.